# Proposed cancel comment button

Tags: feature-request

When typing a comment, there is no button to "cancel" comments.  A cancel button does exist for editing questions... so why not also comments?

Comment: Think before you comment, *suddenly...* No need to cancel them anymore; or, just navigate away from it?

Comment: Right, navigating away from a comment in progress causes it to vanish.  Deleting the text (Control-A and Delete, or your OS's equivalent) also works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you *post* something, there's no cancel button. When you *edit* something, there is. It's simply consistency.

---

When you *edit* a comment, you get the button.

> [image]

When you *post* an answer, you don't.

> [image]

---

Besides the obvious, comments and posts are *very* different.

- Comments are shorter
- You cannot edit comments after a few minutes, so there's little opportunity to have multiple editors open, like when e.g. you're cleaning up a question and its answers.
- You cannot edit others' comments, same as above. How many comments can you edit, really?
- Comments don't have a public revision history, which means accidental edits aren't kept for all eternity.

So even if they did behave differently, it'd not surprise me.

Comment: *> When you post something, there's no cancel button. When you edit something, there is. It's simply consistency.*   The difference is that the Answer box is always there. Comment boxes are hidden and only appear when you click the *add comment* link, and if you change your mind the box remains on screen. (Though to the credit of consistency, when you click the *answer your question* button, the Answer box is displayed and can’t go away since there is no *cancel* button.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with this. Regardless of whether it's about consistency of look or not, if I click on the comment, and then change my mind why am I prevented an easy way to cancel the comment? It feels like I'm now commited... It is such basic web functionality (yes I know, using the word 'basic' here is probably the wrong term).

The only option I've found is to refresh the page. Seems drastic for the sake of a cancel button.